# How can I save multiple messages and save it in separate fields in firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is the firestore document of a certain user:

[image]

This is how I'll save messages to be saved in firestore:

```
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const userRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(uid);
      const ref = userRef.set(
        {
          msg,
        },
        { merge: true }
      );
      console.log(" saved");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <TextField
            value={msg}
            onChange={(e) => setMsg(e.target.value)}
          />
          <Button type="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In this way, I can save the message in the firestore, however, if I'll send another one, it will replace the previous message saved in it. How can I save a message in firestore and save another message without it affecting the previous message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you are overriding the same document in the `users` collection. This is probably (we don't see the entire code) because you don't change the value of `uid` between the two writes. `uid` being the Document ID, it is overwritten (even if you use the `{ merge: true }` option, if the `msg` object contains existing fields, they are overwritten).

You mention that you **save messages**, so I guess you want to save several messages for a given user (this user being identified by `uid`). So you could have a subcollection under the user's document and let Firestore generates a new Document ID each time you add a document to this collection, by using the `add()` method.

Something along the following lines:

```
const messagesCollection = firestore.collection("users").doc(uid).collection('messages');

const messagePayload = {foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo'};
messagesCollection.add({messagePayload});
```

Comment: I'll try doing this too. The messages won't be a lot though, it would either be 1 or 2 messages or less than 5 messages at most